# Derivative of composition

Tags: calculus

I need to express the derivative of $f^{(n)}(x)$ in terms of $f'(x)$, meaning $f$ composed with itself n times.

I was able to express $f(f(x))=f'(f(x))f'(x)$

Is the derivative of the composition $\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} f'(f^{(k)}(x))$ ?

Please help

Comment: Check [Faà di Bruno's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials).

Comment: Do you have a link perhaps? I don't find it

Comment: You can check you formula by induction (replacing $n$ by $k$ in the product).

Comment: @user43418:  I found the link in Mhenni Benghorbal's comment worked.  The more specific Wikipedia page is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula)

Comment: My formula is correct

Comment: @user43418, I don't think it correct as written (need to replace n-1 with k and start the product at k=0. Which is what I think you meant, anyway). See my answer for why.

Comment: @user43418, $f^{(n-1)}$ should be $f^{(k)}$

Comment: $\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} f'(f^{(k)}(x))$

Comment: So now I show that the formula works by induction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: Sometimes $f^{(n)}$ means the $n$th derivative. In this context it means the $n$th iterate.

Put $g(x) = f^{(n)}(x)$ in $\frac{d}{dx} f(g(x)) = g'(x) f'(g(x))$ to get $$\frac{d}{dx} f^{(n+1)}(x) = [\frac{d}{dx} f^{(n)}(x)] f'(f^{(n)}(x)).$$

Using $f^{(0)}(x) = x$ we find, by induction, that $$\frac{d}{dx} f^{(n)}(x) = f'(x) \cdot f'(f(x)) \cdot f'(f^{(2)}(x)) \cdots f'(f^{(n-1)}(x)).$$